# running Xcode 14 source code extension project with default code ,but custom options are not appearing in the editor menu

Tags: xcode

I am developing an Xcode (14.3.1) source editor extension starting with the default code. The OS version is macOS Ventura (13.3.1) . But during runtime my options are not appearing in the editor menu. But some projects downloaded from Github seem to be ok, such as "XCformat". I developed some Xcode extension with Xcode 13 and never met such a problem. Did I miss something?

Here is the screenshots.

I activate the extension:

[image: i'd activate the extension]

Running with Xcode:

[image: running with the xcode]

Still with no custom option in the menu:

[image: and still with no custom option in the menu]

By the way, this extension is auto enabled in the macOS settings:

[image: by the way , this extension is auto enabled in the macos settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including Xcode 14.3.1, it seems that all versions of Xcode 14 are unable to properly create the default source editor extension if the first project did not embed "xcodekit.framework" . In the debug log, you can see: 'IDEExtensionManager: Xcode Extension does not incorporate XcodeKit.' The solution is to add or change the XcodeKit.framework to 'Embedd without signing' in the extension target settings. Then it will work.
[image]